# Do I need two files for JS module run with node CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module that exports a method used in JEST test. I want to run it from command line too.

```
async function doRun() { /* do something */}
exports.doRun = doRun;
```

This works well from JEST, where I import the module and execute the method. But when I call it with `node module.js`, it has no effect because the method is not executed within JS body. To fix it I have to add:

```
doRun().then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

which makes the code work from CLI but it is executed too in JEST just after import.

Am I right that I need to create new file that imports the module and runs the code just for CLI?

```
const module = require('module.js')
doRun().then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

and then run `node module_cli.js`?

Comment: why is there downvote?

Comment: FWIW, I didn't get that either. Node has lots of options, I wouldn't have been surprised to find one that said "load this module then execute this code." (I didn't, but it wouldn't have surprised me. :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much, yeah. :-)

Either that, or use an environment variable

```
async function doRun() { /* do something */}
exports.doRun = doRun;
if (process.env.AUTO_RUN === "Y") {
    doRun().then(() => console.log('finished'));
}
```

and run it like this on *nix:

```
AUTO_RUN=Y node module.js
```

...or on Windows according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-and-using-variable-within-same-command-line-in-windows-cmd-exe) it would be:

```
cmd /V /C "set AUTO_RUN=Y&&node module.js"
```

You could also use the standard `NODE_ENV` environment variable. I haven't gotten deep into Jest, but it might set it to `"testing"` or something like that...